# Why form GUI element update disordered in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, listbox

I have heavy UI operation. I show a heavy realtime chart and one listbox and others control on my form.

Now my problem is UI thread update chart and listbox and other controls disordered as while chart was being updated continously, listbox didn't update for long time.

To resolve this problem I add below line after Add to listbox and my problem solved.

```
Listbox.update();
```

But I think there is a big issue that I am not aware of that and I only hide  that problem .

To sum up why form control update in sloppy or disordered manner?

Comment: Need a bigger code snippet to see whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

In this cases, any component on UI will not be updated until you've completed you heavy operations. I assume that you have your code like this:

```
public protected doSomeThing(Sender e, Evets args)
{
   ...
   Listbox.update();
   HeavyOperations();
   ...
}
```

Your Listbox will not be updated until HeavyOperations() are done. So, you have to run your HeavyOperations() on a different Thread.

Take a look at this: [Threading in Windows Forms](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml)
Read this reference, there's a perfect example of what you need to learn and execute.

Comment: please notice that I do  heavyoperation  on non UI thread and do cross thread operation for add to listbox and update listbox.  now I saw except Listox there is other form control that update inside timer tik event but there are freeze on the form